# How can I send ALT+ENTER using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, I'd like to make the program full screen when the program is run, without being windowed. Pressing ALT+ENTER allows the program to be full screen when the program is run. Here is what I have so far:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("ENTER%")
```

Here is a resource from Microsoft that will REALLY help you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

All I want to do is to send the combination ALT+ENTER using PowerShell. Please no other languages unless it's batch, and I don't want an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use:

 `%` for **alt** 

and 

`~` for **enter**

```
yourapplication.SendKeys('%~')
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa202943(v=office.10)

Comment: Thank you! Awaiting trial and then I will put the check mark. Sorry for the wait.